# Does Modernizr load the script once?

Tags: javascript, firebug, modernizr, yepnope

I'm conditionally loading the javascript code using the Modernizr's loader (integrated yepnope.js). Here's my code:

```
Modernizr.load({
test: Modernizr.geolocation,
yep: ['js/get-native-geo-data.js','https://www.google.com/jsapi'],
nope: ['js/get-geo-data-by-ip.js','https://www.google.com/jsapi'],
complete : function () {
    google.load("maps", "3", 
                {other_params: "sensor=false", 'callback':init});
});
```

It works, but the Network tab in both FireBug and Google Developers tools shows that it loads get-native-geo-data.js twice. I've added a console.log() in the native-geo-data.js, and prints the message only once. So what makes both FireBug and Dev Tools report two network calls both return 200, size 3K?

This is how Firebug reports the response header for each GET (they are the same):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 20 Dec 2012 19:39:52 GMT
Server: HttpComponents/4.1.3
Content-Length: 3054
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Connection: keep-alive
```

After running it though the Charles monitoring tool I see the same results - the function gets called twice. So where is the bug - in Modernizr, in yepnope, or in my head?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've seen it in the yepnope documentation:

> I'm seeing two requests in my dev tools, why is it loading everything
>   twice? Depending on your browser and your server this could mean a
>   couple different things. Due to the nature of how yepnope works, there
>   are two requests made for every file. The first request is to load the
>   resource into the cache and the second request is to execute it (but
>   since it's in the cache, it should execute immediately). Seeing two
>   requests is pretty normal as long as the second request is cached. If
>   you notice that the second request isn't cached (and your script load
>   times are doubling), then make sure you are sending the correct cache
>   headers to allow the caching of your scripts. This is vital to
>   yepnope. It will not work without proper caching enabled. We actually
>   test to make sure things aren't loaded twice in our test suite, so if
>   you think we may have a bug in your browser regarding double loading,
>   we encourage you to run the test suite to see if the double loading
>   test passes.

Comment: Thanks for the reference in the yepnope doc. It's definitely not cached in my case. The yepnope doc doesn't tell how to properly specify the caching policy though. The only other reference I found there is to use preload, but this is exactly what I don't want to do - I need to load either one or the other script.  I tried using preload prefix
yep: ['preload!js/get-native-geo-data.js','https://www.google.com/jsapi']
, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Tried using <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public"> in the HTML file - didn't help either.

Comment: Also you can read this issue here https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/issues/10 Looks like you can't 100% rely on Firebug info in this case.

Comment: I've read all the discussions available online, but three different monitoring tools are reporting duplicate downloads that are shown separately on the timeline and take real time, not just 1 milisecond for reading from cache. On the other hand, all these reporting tools print on the console my debug message from the script being downloaded only once. 

It would be nice if the yepnope folks would explain why the monitoring tools show it this way?  I tried to open this as a new issue at yepnope's github site, but got a "Not allowed" error.